# Array with Values and Pointers

Tags: c++

I have an array of 64 bit unsigned integers. Is it possible to assign some pointers of an array in some positions of it. I mean:

```
array [0] = Integer
array [1] = Integer
array [2] = Pointer to array
array [3] = Pointer to array
array [4] = Integer
```

Can anybody help me how to do that ?

Comment: It's very ugly practice (in C++ not in C) to interpret pointers as numbers (and vice versa). It's in general, but according to your example it's ugly ^ 2, because - how would you reinterpret them back to pointers ? Maybe the best way is to revise an architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to turn `array` into an array of

```
union {
  uint64_t   intval;
  uintptr_t  ptrval;
};
```

and work with that.

You will, of course, need some way to know whether a particular element stores an integer or a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
array[3] = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer);
```

(`uintptr_t` is from `<cstdint>`)

Try to avoid doing this if possible though. Can you rethink your design?

Comment: Thanks but would "array[3] = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer);" it create an pointer to an array of specified type and length and how to access that ? Can you please give a simple code to illustrate above fact ?

Comment: @user1838343 you lose all type information when you do this, so you can't get its length. You just have to `reinterpret_cast` it back into the pointer... What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I want to put integers into arrays. If positions have lots of values (an array of values) I want to create an pointer array and store values into it. Then I have to access those values accordingly.

Comment: I know I will loose information of the length. But, I know how much integers it contains when an pointer will appear.

Comment: You still need to keep track of whether the value is just an integer or a pointer - you are much better off using a structure that is just pointers [remember, you also need something to indicate the length of your array - be that an "endmarker" or a length-variable - the latter may be a tiny bit easier].

Comment: @user1838343 but what are you *actually* trying to do? The problem you're solving? Anyway, can't use a `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: The problem is that you don't know what is a pointer and what isn't - there is no arbitrary way to determine that.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that one. @ Mats

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: you want to have an array, each element of which could be either a number or another array of number ? If so, make an array of `std::vector`s, and keep only one value if you want to store a number. Like this:

```
typedef std::vector< long long > I64Vector;
std::vector< I64Vector > array;
array.push_back( I64Vector( { 42 } ) ); // store one integer ( 42 ) in array[ 0 ]
array.push_back( I64Vector( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ) ); // store 5 integers in array[ 1 ]
//... etc.
// accessing them
long long num = array[ 0 ][ 0 ]; // 42
const I64Vector & subarray = array[ 1 ];
long subNumber1 = subarray[ 0 ]; // 1
long subNumber2 = subarray[ 1 ]; // 2
//... etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the type your `array` element to something that can store integers and pointers (or preferably `std::vector<std::uint64_t>`).  A type-safe approach is to use 
[`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
std::vector<boost::variant<std::uint64_t, std::vector<std::uint64_t>>> array;
array.push_back(1);
array.push_back(2);
array.push_back(std::vector<std::uint64_t>{4,5,6});

if (int* x = boost::get<std::uint64_t>(array[0])) { ... }
if (std::vector<std::uint64_t>* x 
        = boost::get<std::vector<std::uint64_t>>(array[2])) { ... }
```

If you want to use builtin arrays instead of vectors you can use unions instead of `boost::variant`:

```
 struct IntOrArray
 {
   bool isInt;
   union {
     std::uint64_t int_value;
     std::uint64_t* array_value;
   }
 };

 std::vector<IntOrArray> array;
 IntOrArray a1;
 IntOrArray a1.isInt = true;
 IntOrArray a1.int_value = 1;
 array.push_back(a1);

 IntOrArray a2;
 IntOrArray a2.isInt = false;
 IntOrArray a2.array_value = arrayYouGotElsewhere;
 array.push_back(a2);

 if (array[0].isInt) { ... }
```

C++11 allows you to put `std::vector`s into unions but this is not supported by all compilers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can do that,

a[3] = (unsigned long long)&a; (in windows)

and to get back the pointer value,
(unsigned long long *)a[3]

Comment: Why did you point out "in windows" ? This code wouldn't work in Linux or MacOS ?